# Having trouble to mock Rest Template postForEntity()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to mock restTemplate.postForEntity method,

The actual method call is:

```
final UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).queryParam("string", "query string");

final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
JSONObject responseObject;
response = restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.build().toUri(), entity, String.class);
responseObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
```

What I have in my test class is:

```
String response = "{" +
                "\"name\": \"john\"," +
                "\"id\": \"123\"" +
                "}";
when(mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), any())).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(response));
```

Even though im mocking the response im not able to retrieve the response back and returning null value as response.
Appreciate any help !

Comment: Pls show how you inject mocked restTempate to your component

Comment: @Mock
    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

Comment: This show how you define the mock, not how you inject it. (Any relevant annotations on test class like runner / extesnion will be useful as well)

Comment: @Lesiak `code`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ABCServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ABCServiceImpl abcService;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate; } `code`

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the wrong overload of the postForEntity method.
Check [RestTemplate javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html):

```
<T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
<T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(URI url, Object request, Class<T> responseType)
```